# What do you call the piece that holds a router bit's guide wheel in place?

Tags: routers, guide

In the pic below, there's a black ring that holds the bearing guide wheel in place against the router bit.  I need another one of those so I can position the guide wheel higher up on the shank.  Knowing what that piece is called will give me something to actually search for.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often called [Stop collar](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stop%20collar%22&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=1Dl&tbo=u&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ka8OUcv9J8SvqgG454H4AQ&ved=0CDMQsAQ&biw=1250&bih=792) or [shaft collar](http://www.ruland.com/ps_collars_shaft_sc.asp).

Comment: I've also seen [lock collar](http://www.freudtools.com/p-243-repair-parts.aspx).

Comment: Collit.....old school name

Comment: @shirlock- do you mean collet? I disagree. A collet provides a clamping force, often to hold a tool, to transmit a motive force. This is simply a stop to prevent parts from sliding up the shaft. IMHO of course :)

Comment: My bad,  a collet is a type of chuck, like on a dremel tool etc.  OPPS!!!!

Comment: Shaft collar wins!  http://www.menards.com/main/search.html?search=shaft+collar&sf_categoryHierarchy=&queryType=category